# Passing the model class name in laravel using dynamic array

Tags: php, laravel, models

I have an array ($models) which has the names of my modal classes :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\systemActions;

use Storage;
use App\Accident;
use App\Company;
use App\Driver;
use App\Employee;
use App\Expert;
use App\InputTransaction;
use App\Notification;
use App\Receipt;
use App\Person;
use App\Transaction;
use App\Group;
use App\User;
use App\Permission;
use App\Witness;
use App\Companynote;
use App\RejectedReceipt;
use App\DataEntryNote;
use App\Task;
use App\Setting;
use App\RealEstate;
use App\Oldreportpayment;
use App\Freelancerdataentryaccident;
use App\UserFlow;
use App\Page;
use App\Log;
use App\Damagedetection;
use App\Datarequest;
use App\Eperson;
use App\Edriver;
use App\Eaccident;
use App\Erealestate;
use App\Subcompany;
use App\Subcompanyaccident;
use Faker\Provider\tr_TR\DateTime;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Hash;
use Validator;
ob_start();
session_start();
class readController extends Controller
{
 $modals=['Accident','Company','Companynote','Damagedetection','Dataentrynote','Datarequest',
             'Driver','Eaccident','Edriver','Eperson','Erealestate','Freelancerdataentryaccident','Garage'
              ,'Group','Kashef','Notification','Oldreportpayment','Person','Realestate','Receipt','Setting',
              'Rejectedreceipt','Subcompany','Subcompanyaccident','Task','Transaction','Userflow','Witness'];
```

i was trying to use them in the following code statement :

```
$modals[$x]::create($DB2_Data[$x]);
```

but iam getting this error :

> Class 'Accident' not found

---

on the other hand, if I put this or anything  that is in the model's array, it works fine

```
Accident::create($DB2_Data[$x]);
```

so can anyone give me a solution for this problem.

Comment: try `$modals=['App\Accident']`

Comment: not sure but you might want to try `'App\\' . $modals[$x]::create($DB2_Data[$x]);`

Comment: @Sohel0415 that fixed it

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti this didn't work, but thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

so as our friend suggested up there we need to add them in the array as following : `$modals=['App\Accident']`
thank you